# selenium select by visible text in python

Tags: python, selenium

Hi I am trying to use selenium to select an item from a dropdown using the actual text not the value option. My script pulls states out of a list and iterates through the states selecting the dropdown that matches the list. 
When I try the following code it throws out an error:

```
for agentinfo1, agentstate1 in zip(agentinfo, agentstate):
    select2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#selst" %agentstate1)
    select2.click()
```

> select2 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector("#selst" %agentstate1)
>   TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

I'm wondering if the error is thrown out becuase when I grab the data that I put in my list I append a "\n" but even when I take out that code it does not work.

Answer (score 2):

you are using css IDs instead of CSS classes. select2 is pointer to the select element, if your text is exactly the same as in your variable

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

for agentinfo1, agentstate1 in zip(agentinfo, agentstate):
    select2 = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("<some id of the select element>")).select_by_visible_text(agentstate)
```

if it is only partial match you can try this (case insensitive partial match):

```
from selenium.webdriver.support.ui import Select

for agentinfo1, agentstate1 in zip(agentinfo, agentstate):
    select2 = Select(self.driver.find_element_by_id("<some id of the select element>"))
    for each_option in select2.options:
        if agentstate.lower in each_option.text.lower:
            select2.select_by_index(int(each_option.get_attribute("value")))
```

Comment: Minor typo: it should be `agentstate.lower()` instead of `agentstate.lower`. Also, `casefold()` can be a better approach in case of multiple languages involved